# How to combine 'COUNTIF' with 'OR'

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with the following cell values:

```
ce
Km
st
Ge
eS
k
lm
LS
lt
```

I would like to count any cell that contains the letter "s", "t", "m", or "g" but I do not want to double count a cell that has a combination of those letters in it. For example, a cell that has "ts" I would like to count just once, instead of counting both the "s" and the "t".

Is it possible to do this with a formula?

I've tried this formula:

```
SUM(COUNTIF(G4:G12,{"*s*","*t*","*g*","*m*"}))
```

which returns 3 (I think it only counts anything with "s").

and this formula:

```
 "sumproduct(len($G$4:$G$29)
-len
(substitute
(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE
(upper($G$4:$G$29)
,""T"",""""),""S"",""""),""G"",""""),""M"","""")))"
```

which returns 8 because it counts the "st" cell as 2.

Answer (score 3):

A bit shorter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A9,"(?i)[stgm]"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You fail to mention whether case sensitive, but assuming your list is in G4:G12 you might try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--(len(G4:G12)<>len(regexreplace(G4:G12,"s|t|m|g","")))))
```

[SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
[LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Prepend the second `s` with `(?i)` for case insensitive.